# Illegal to access non-static method questaSim

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog

I get the error `Illegal to access non-static method foo in static method.` when i try to compile with `vlog` while `vcs` let's it pass through without a sweat. Anyone have anytips how to solve this.

```
function foo_class::error(string expression, string filename, int linenumber);
  foo_base::foo_base_error(expression, filename, linenumber);
endfunction
```

Comment: Should `expr` be `expresion`?

Comment: yes sorry i#ll fix it

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Show us what `foo_class` and `foo_base` look like (the structure, who inherits from whom, how the functions are defined, i.e. with what modifiers, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming `foo_class` a child of `foo_base`, in which case use `super.foo_base_error` instead of `foo_base::foo_base_error`

To call a non-static method, it needs to belong to a object. It cannot be called directly from the class scope. Static methods can be called directly from the class scope.

There should be a warning in your VCS log file. The simulator is likely being forgiving and either making `foo_base_error` static or swapping `foo_base::` to `super.` internally. questaSim is being more strict in following the LRM.

References [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html):

- § 8.10 *Static methods*
- § 8.15 *Super*
- § 8.24 *Out-of-block declarations*

Comment: `foo_base::foo_base_error` could be legal, but you haven't shown the complete prototypes of all methods involved. Are there actually static methods in your code?

Answer (score 0):

This is what the SV 2012 standard states in section 8.10 Static Methods:

> A static method has no access to non-static members (class properties
>   or methods), but it can directly access static class properties or
>   call static methods of the same class.

You seem to be trying to access a static method of a different class, which is against the wording of the LRM. If `foo_base` is the base class of `foo_class`, then `foo_class` also contains the `foo_base_error(...)` function. Try changing it to:

```
function foo_class::error(string expression, string filename, int linenumber);
  foo_class::foo_base_error(expression, filename, linenumber);
endfunction
```

If it is not, then you're out of luck. It seems that VCS has a looser interpretation with respect to static methods than QuestaSim.